# Handling timers for many users in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, cron

I'm building a web app in Node/Express such that users can set a timer so that a certain task gets executed or repeated. My question is how can I set timer for many users with an event triggered after deadline. I **don't** want to handle this on the client side beacuse users can close the browser. A good example of this is services such as pingdom.com that allow you to set timer and send a ping every X minutes to your server. How can this be acheived?
I hope I don't get many negatives for asking this and I'm also not asking you guys to write me the code. I simply want to know a robust strategy to solve this problem. 
Here is what I thought about:

1. Save the endtime in db and using a cron job check every second to see if the time is up (This is not really good in my opinion since the query and all calculations might take more than 1 second)
2. Somehow assign a variable to setInterval and store them in a global list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web app would have a more responsive UI and your backend would scale better if each client held its own timer.  Closing the browser wouldn't be a problem.

- Persist the `endtime` in a DB in your server for the specific question.
- On the client side, retrieve the `endtime` from the server, and use JavaScript to create a timer that would alert the user their time has expired.
- On the server side, have an additional check that rejects answers if the answer is being submitted past `endtime` to prevent clients from cheating.

Comment: The problem is the clients (those who answer) are in an IRC channel and I cannot run javascript for them. The only person who has access to the UI (client code) is the person who creates the question which if closes the browser I cannot send the triggered event to the server.